# Why wont these seams tighten up/ make contact? No matter how big I make it, no matter what I set the collision to it still wont tighten

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

[image]

I've recently discovered that the ability to sew clothes exists in Blender. Really cool idea and I love it but I can't ever seem to get seams to completely pull together and am left with these unsightly spaces. Is there anything I can do as I'd like to move on to a more advanced article of clothing.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I have never had this problem. Is your spring force too low? Is the cloth really heavy, like denim?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Sewing force is max and I have the vertex weight set to the standard for cotton (in blender) which I believe is like 0.3kg off the top of my head. Regardless, I've tried messing with the weight and get the same results :(

Comment: Is the clothing too tight? If the shirt is too small, it won’t fit.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard so ive seen that suggested elsewhere but even if I scale up the shirt so its like a parachute hanging off him the seams always stay at the same place. Ohers have suggested to me that its due to collision settings but I have them all set as low as possible now and cant get the thing to work

Comment: Umm... is it possible there is a transparent material there?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Nah there's no transparent material. I really hope they flesh out this clothes sewing functionality!

Comment: It does work, I know it does. I’ve used it. I don’t know what’s happening here.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Ive ended up downloading a third party add on called 'Modelling Cloth' by Rich Colburn. It gives a lot more control of the sewing and some other parameters but admittedly the 'cloth' doesnt look as nice or natural as what's achievable with blenders built in. Check out here -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4I5NGSQlgMo

Comment: I had the same problem and what made it better for me was just adding more edges for the shirt to sew with and it does come out tighter.